# 2 question on solvable group's property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A theorem says a finite group G is solvable if and only if for every divisor n of $\vert G\vert$ such that (n,$\frac{\vert G\vert}{n})=1$,G has a subgroup of order n.

1. Does this imply that G must containt prime factors upto power 1.(i.e. $\vert G\vert$=$p_{1}p_{2}...p_{n}$ where all $p_{i}\neq p_{j}$ for $i\neq j$? I thought by moding out operation say a composition series for solvable group $1=G_{0},G_{1},...,G_{n-1},G=G_{n}$ such that $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is abelian, G/N is abelian by definition of G solvable. Then every prime factor has an element of order of that prime number. Hence, $\vert G\vert$=$p_{1}p_{2}...p_{n}$ and they are all different.
2. Can one also conclude that any subgroup of G such that N normal to G, there will be a composition series $1=G_{0},...,G_{m-1},N=G_{m},G_{m+1},...,G=G_{n}$ such that $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is abelian? I knew this is true for composition series but I do not know whether this is true for solvable groups.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this characterization of solvable groups? To answer your questions, (1) is false: take $G = \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p$. (2) Follows from the Jordan-Holder theorem, which says that all composition series for a given group are equivalent. Since $G$ is solvable, it has a composition series with abelian composition factors. Take any composition series $\{e\} \lhd \dots \lhd N \lhd \dots \lhd G$, and, up to isomorphism, the set of subsequent quotients of this series is the same as that of the abelian series. In particular, the quotients are abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, $|G|$ need not be square-free. For example, any abelian group satisfies that condition.
2. Yes. Since $G$ is solvable, $N$ and $G/N$ are both solvable. A composition series of $G$ can be constructed from that of $N$ and $G/N$:

   - $1,G_0,\dots, G_{m-1},G_m=N$ is a composition series of $N$,
   - $1,G_{m+1}/N,\dots, G/N$ is a composition series of $G/N$.

Comment: So is 2) true for any composition series or this is just saying there is one special or maybe some other but not all composition series such that $G_{i}/G_{i-1}$ is abelian?

Comment: This one is specifically chosen to contain $N$.