# Characterization of solvable groups in terms of subgroups of certain orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, solvable-groups

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883123/2-question-on-solvable-groups-property#comment1822737_883123), the OP mentions the following result: a finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if

$$\text{for all $n$ dividing $|G|$ such that $\gcd(\frac{|G|}{n},n)=1$, $G$ has a subroup order $n$}. \,\, (*)$$

This was surprising to me: for one thing, this together with the Sylow theorems implies [the Burnside Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem). The OP didn't provide a reference, and a proof wasn't apparent to me. A cursory web search and a perusal of my algebra texts yielded no results.

On the other hand, a counterexample didn't immediately come to mind -- but it would suffice to find a group of order less than $60$ which does not satisfy $(*)$, or to find a finite non-abelian simple group satisfying $(*)$.

**My questions is this:** is this characterization of solvable groups valid? I'd like either a proof, a reference to a proof, or a counterexample. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik perfect, want to make this into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hall subgroups and Hall' Theorem are described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup. The converse of Hall's Theorem uses Burnsides' Theorem.

Comment: This theorem is proven in [Kurzweil, Stellmacher - The Theory of Finite Groups]. See Theorem 6.4.10.